# Change tab Bar programatically swift xcode 9 iOS

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller, tabbar, xcode9, swift4

I have an alert controller which have two buttons "OK" & "Cancel". When user click on Ok button then tab bar index should change. But i implement it don't work. How i can handle it.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
{
    tabBarSelectedIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex

    if videoFileNames.count != 0
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Your selected data will be lost", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let btnOk = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action -> Void in
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = self.tabBarSelectedIndex
            }
        let btnCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(btnOk)
        alert.addAction(btnCancel)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: show your complete code. Where you added selectedIndex code

Comment: please check my update question.